# What customisation options are available for the new unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, 11.10

I'm looking to understand what are the customisation options available for the unity launcher in 11.10.

Is it possible to modify?:

- size of launcher, (smaller than 32 px? bigger than 64?)
- position of the launcher
- color and opacity
- item organization, (move items freely anywhere in the launcher, as workspaces for ex.)
- any kind of other modification available.

What tools do I need to install to perform these changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Is it possible to modify:

- **The size of launcher, (smaller than 32 px? bigger than 64?)?**

  - No.
- **The position of the launcher?**

  - No.
- **The colour and opacity?**

  - Colour: no. Opacity: yes.
- **Item organization, (move items freely anywhere in the launcher, as workspaces for ex.*)**?

  - No. This seems to have been postponed or decided against.

---

### Is any kind of other modification available.

- Yes.

  - It is now possible to enable edge illumination.
  - Dynamic quicklists are supported when using libunity.

---

### What tools do I need to install to perform these changes?

- As before, you need to install (Compiz Config Settings Manager) [ccsm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ccsm) [image: Install ccsm].

---

**Screenshot:**
[image: example screen shot.]

### **You can move any icons except the Dash, Workspace switcher, Mounted drives, and Trash.**

Comment: thank you for the very clear answer, very useful for me! i'll mark it as solved. if something changes until release date please update us! thx again

Comment: You *can* re-arrange launcher items. You have been able to since 11.04

Comment: i didn't mean the regular icons. i did mean the workspaces icon and the trash etc.. i can't get them to the top right?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I've added that to my answer for clarity (since the way he asked, that can be overlooked).

Comment: @suli8 no, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the way the dash shows, a netbook or as a desktop; you  just need to type in the terminal:

To Netbook

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'
```

[image: DesktopDash]

To Desktop

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Netbook'
```

[image: NetbookDash]

Comment: This was available for Natty - this isnt specific to 11.10 as the OPs question requested.

Comment: @fossfreedom , in 11.10 you can maximize or minimize the dash as this answer suggested by the maximize button above the launcher? just good to know :)